# Change definition of Bootstrap default sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I know about [generating a custom version of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) , but i dont want to use that. (because I have made a lot of changes to my `bootstrap.min.css` and i dont remember them)
Now I want to change definition of `sm` and set it to `500px`.
Can someone help me with this? tnx ;)

Comment: Hmm, but as soon as you change "sm" to `500px` you'll have to regenerate the css. There's no "definition of sm" in the generated css (therefore no such thing in your modified `bootstrap.min.css`). So what you really need (assuming you want to keep your other changes in `bootstrap.min.css`) is just to find all occurrences of media queries corresponding to `sm` size and change those to `500px`.

Comment: tnx about your help. ok so now you say that i should change all media queries corresponding to 'sm' size. How many are they?

Comment: At least every `@media (min-width: 768)`. Could be others (basically every media query having `-sm-` selectors in).